# bringSubviewToFront(_:) function breaks a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a `BoardView` class which subclasses `UIView`. It has several subviews, which all have their own `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I use this recognizer to drag around a subview inside my `BoardView` instance, as such:

```
func pieceDragged(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let pieceView = recognizer.view!
    if recognizer.state == .Began || recognizer.state == .Changed {
        // move the pieceView by the appropriate amount
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        pieceView.center = CGPoint(x: pieceView.center.x + translation.x, y: pieceView.center.y + translation.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, inView: self)
    } else if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

This works fine.

The problem is that I want the subview that is being dragged around to be on top of all of its siblings, so I made my `BoardView` instance the delegate of each gesture recognizer and overrode this function:

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let pieceView = gestureRecognizer.view!
    bringSubviewToFront(pieceView)
    return true
}
```

This seems to break the entire gesture recognizer: if I attempt to drag aroudn a subview, the `pieceDragged(_:)` function is called exactly once (where the state of the recognizer is `.Began`), but no more than that.

If I comment out `bringSubviewToFront(pieceView)`, my code works as before - I can drag around any subview, but it's below some of its siblings.

I'm clueless. What could be going on here?

Comment: I've literally just recreated a simple `BoardView` class with the same two exact methods you have and it works fine. Is there anything else going on in this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I replaced all my subviews in the `layoutSubviews()` method (which is automatically called after `bringToFront(_:)` is called).

Comment: While I can see how this was programmer error great job posting this and answer. I was facing same problem with also odd behavior only to realise layoutSubviews() was being called when I didn't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are going round the houses as well and implementing a method that doesn't really make sense. The delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` is all about should this recogniser actually start detecting not a place to perform an action.

You already have a suitable place to perform the action you want you could simply update your code to be

```
func pieceDragged(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
  guard let pieceView = recognizer.view else {
    return
  }

  switch recognizer.state {
  case .Began:
    pieceView.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(pieceView)

  case .Changed:
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, inView: self)

    pieceView.center = CGPoint(x: pieceView.center.x + translation.x, y: pieceView.center.y + translation.y)

  default: ()
  }
}
```

Comment: I put that line of code in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` because it only needs to be executed once, and the `pieceDragged(_:)` function is called every time I move my finger. Anyways, I tried putting it in that function, like you suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: I've updated it so it will only call the `bringToFront(_:)` once. Now see my original comment - the code you pasted works fine in a new project for me, is there anything else you are doing?

Comment: I started to comment things out and see where it goes wrong, and it turns out I call a function in which I layout all of the subviews from the `layoutSubviews()` method, which in turn is called each time I bring a subview to the front. I didn't realise this happened until I set a break point.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to solve this? I lose my reference to `pieceView` once `layoutSubviews()` gets called (because I layout my subviews by removing all the `pieceViews` and replacing them by new ones).

Comment: Why are you removing and adding them all?

Comment: Because I'm asking the delegate (conforming to the `BoardViewDelegate` protocol) where the pieces have to end up... I guess my design is just wrong, but it was the best design I could come up with. I chose this one because I want to have multiple `BoardView` instances throughout the app, and don't want multiple view controllers to have to perform the same tasks.

Comment: If it's just asking the delegate for the position why does it need to remove/add can it not just move the items? Would need to see more code really to help any more